# How do I return one specific attribute of a JSON response from a HTTP request in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a HTTP request to fetch details for a table. Earlier, the response was a JSON which looked like this :

```
{"TotalRejectedRequests":0,"TotalDrafts":41,"RequestsPendingApproval":6,"TotalApprovedRequests":13}
```

For this type of response, I was returning the data like this :

```
return this.http.post<Snapshot>('https://xyz.abc/fetchData', details);
```

where Snapshot was the name of the interface to which the response was mapped.

Now the response that I get from the HTTP request has changed to this :

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        "TotalRejectedRequests": 0,
        "TotalDrafts": 2,
        "RequestsPendingApproval": 0,
        "TotalApprovedRequests": 1
    },
    "errorMsg": null
}
```

How do I now return only the value of "data" in this response JSON mapped to the Snapshot interface I already have?

EDIT : Igor's answer solved the previous issue but I have 2 different issues now. 
 1. What do I do if I don't have any interface to map my response to? I have another service where I was just returning the entire JSON without mapping it to an interface? Now I just want to return the data value of that JSON like shown above? How do I do that?

2. If I'm using subscribe or toPromise, will that cause any issue or will there be any other way to do it?

Comment: Change to `post<{ data: Snapshot }>` and fix errors until the compiler stops complaining at you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map to [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) your data to the expected response.

```
return this.http.post<{data: Snapshot}>('https://xyz.abc/fetchData', details)
   .pipe(map(_ => _.data));
```

Do not forget to import `map`

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error saying "Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?"

Comment: @AkshatSood - you need to import `map`, see update.

Comment: Yup. I thought I'd already imported that. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: What if I don't have any interface to which I can map the data? For a different service, earlier I was just returning the JSON I got from the service without using any interface. How do I return in that case?

Comment: @AkshatSood - use `any` if you do not want to map types but one of the main reasons to use typescript is type safety which you would then not be taking advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap your data with rxjs mapping operator

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
return this.http.post<Snapshot>('https://xyz.abc/fetchData', details).pipe(
  map(({ data }) => data)
);
```

Also you can do a lot more with rxjs operators take look at their [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Comment: I stand corrected, I did not realize that syntax was valid.

Comment: @Igor that is spread operator in action on function arguments :)

Comment: @Xesenix you probably mean **destructuring**